# mysqli_query INSERT no guarda la captura de datos

Tags: php, mysqli, php7

Tengo un sitio web que debo migrar a la versión PHP7 pero no me guarda la captura de datos

```
 <?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if ($_POST['docente']!= "")
{
 if ($_POST['r1'] >50 || $_POST['r2'] >50 || $_POST['r3'] >50 || $_POST['r4'] >50 || $_POST['r5'] >50 || $_POST['r6'] >50 || $_POST['r7'] >50 || $_POST['r1'] <0 || $_POST['r2'] <0 || $_POST['r3'] <0 || $_POST['r4'] <0 || $_POST['r5'] <0 || $_POST['r6'] <0 || $_POST['r7'] <0)
  {
 echo "la calificacion es entre 0 y 50";
  }
  else
  {
if (($_POST["MM_insert"]) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form2")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO fa1 (cod_alumno, docente, programa , materia, grupo, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, ob) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['cod_alumno'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['docente'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['programa'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['materia'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['grupo'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['r1'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['r2'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['r3'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['r4'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['r5'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['r6'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['r7'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['d4'], "text"));

  include ("conexionfed.php");
  $Result1 =  mysqli_query($conn, $insertSQL);

echo '<script language="javascript">  var x ="'.$_POST['docente'].'"; alert("el docente "+x+" A sido calificad@"); </script>';
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Haz la prueba a insertar un único dato de la forma más sencilla posible para detectar qué puede estar fallando: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Y modifica la consulta para aportar la tabla con algún registro en SQL, a ver si damos con ello

Comment: En tu funcion utilizas las funciones `mysql_real_escape_string` y `mysql_escape_string` que en PHP7 fueron eliminadas. Por otro lado te recomendaria el uso de sentencias preparadas.

Answer (score 0):

En una revisión rápida por que el código no se visualiza correctamente, podría ser por que tu case "long" no tiene valores.

Podrías mostrar lo que haz hecho y que error te muestra.

Comment: @GianBros Esta respuesta tiene más pinta de comentario que de respuesta, mejor elimínala y conviértela en comentario no sea que alguien la vote negativamente por responder a una pregunta incorrectamente planteada :)

Comment: @Me arroja el mensaje que esta en el sistema para confirmación del registro pero al revisar la base de datos no esta almacenado